# Debouncing all instances of a certain javascript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a javascript in my application that needs to be debounced.

The relevant html of the page is as follows:

```
<li id="liRetailer_10"> 
  <a href="javascript:;">
     <label class="checkbox-list">
       <input type="checkbox" id="retailer_10" value="MenuItem" class="taggable" onclick="doTaggableChange(this)">MenuItem</label>
  </a>
</li>
```

There are multiple li elements like this and they are used to call a function that executes a query on the database.

I want to execute the function after the user stops clicking these elements for a while, otherwise it gets called for each click, slowing down the system unnecessarily.

ie: user clicks on element1 and then immediately clicks on element2, currently the script executes twice. I want the function to run once.

The method that is called onclick is as follows:

```
function doTaggableChange(e) {
    var index = $(e).attr('id').indexOf('_');
    var type = $(e).attr('id').substring(0, index);
    var id = $(e).attr('id').replace(type + '_', '');
    var val = $(e).val();
    var data = {
    id: $(e).attr('id'),
    value: val
    };
    var checked = $(e).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
      $('#tagsinput').tagsinput('add', data);
        addFilter(type, id);
        } else {
          $('#tagsinput').tagsinput('remove', data);
          removeFilter(type, id);
        }
  }
```

To this end I tried the following assuming this would add a debounce for each time an element with the class:"taggable" is clicked using jQuery:

```
(function() {
     var dprocess = $.debounce(process, 5000);
     $('.taggable').click(function() {
         dprocess();
     });
}());
```

However this did not work.

My question is: How do I globally debounce all instances of this "doTaggableChangeScript"?

Comment: _I want to make this query after the user stops clicking on these elements._ seems a bit strange. can you define it more?

Comment: I tried to explain it more clearly. I hope it helps

Comment: absolutely. you can use to have a custom debouncing method for it.

Comment: you can see the answer posted you can do something like this.

Comment: i tried and it seems to be in the right track but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debounce` from `underscore.js` http://underscorejs.org/#debounce as follows

```
var doTaggableChange = _.debounce(function(e) {
                                    alert("doTaggableChangeFired", e);
                                  }, 300)
```

The passed function which will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked.

```js
var doTaggableChange = _.debounce(function(e) {
      var index = $(e).attr('id').indexOf('_');
      var type = $(e).attr('id').substring(0, index);
      var id = $(e).attr('id').replace(type + '_', '');
      var val = $(e).val();
      var data = {
        id: $(e).attr('id'),
        value: val
      };
      var checked = $(e).is(':checked');
      if (checked) {
        $('#tagsinput').tagsinput('add', data);
        addFilter(type, id);
      } else {
        $('#tagsinput').tagsinput('remove', data);
        removeFilter(type, id);
      }
    }, 300);
```

Comment: _I want to make this query after the user stops clicking on these elements._ this doesn't answer it.

Comment: Bind the `doTaggableChange` function to your click event. Then the passed function with `alert` in it will only be called when user have clicked on the element have not clicked again in last 300 milliseconds.

Comment: I tried but when I include the first bit under my doTaggableChange function it throws an error saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var". I don't get the syntax at all.

Comment: modified the script a bit to make it fit and works now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```js
var time; // make a global var time.
$.fn.debounce = function(e, cb, el) {
  if (time) { // clear the time if there are already any timeout initialized.
    clearTimeout(time);
  } // clear the prev timeout and just allow the latest one to debounce

  time = setTimeout(function() {
    cb(e, el); // now call the function call to log only once
  }, 2000);

};

var doTaggableChange = function(e, el) {
  console.log("doTaggableChangeFired", e);
  alert("doTaggableChangeFired :::::: "+el.value);
};

$(function() {
  $('.taggable').click(function(e) {
    $(this).debounce(e, doTaggableChange, this);
    // bound the event on the selector and applied the custom debounce on it.
    // args passed are event, function to call and element itself.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-list">
  <input type="checkbox" value="MenuItem1" class="taggable">MenuItem1</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="MenuItem2" class="taggable">MenuItem2</label>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it the script still fires immediately, it didn't break anything though so it seems like we are on the right track.